# How do I solve this SDE (stochastic differential equation)?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I am stuck in trying to solve this equation
\begin{align}
d X_t = - b^2 X_t (1 - X_t)^2 dt + b \sqrt{1 - X_t^2} dW_t
\end{align}

Here, $b$ is a constant. I am trying to apply my usual methods for solving SDEs, but nothing is working out. E.g. I tried applying Ito's formula to $h(X_t)$ and choosing $h$ so that the $dW_t$ term is constant, but it didn't work out. I also tried setting $X_t = h(t, W_t)$, applying Ito's formula and choosing $h$ to match the terms in the SDE. That also did not work out. What is the correct method here? N.B. I have the solution and can provide it if necessary. But I really would like to know the method that is used. Many thanks.

Edit:
Here is another thing that I tried. Once again, I applied Ito's formula to $X_t = h(t, W_t)$. Then, in the equation for $d[h(X_t)]$, I tried to make the $dt$ term equal to a constant (say $1$ or $b^2$). When I did this, I got a second order ODE. I reduce the order of the ODE and tried to solve it using the integrating factor method. But the integral in the integrating factor doesn't integrate exactly, and so I know that I am going down the wrong path. Please could somebody steer me in the right direction? Many thanks.

Comment: Please do write out the system of equations that you get when you set up Ito's formula with some $h$. It is a somewhat tedious task and it would help your answerer to not have to do it. Also, feel free to present the solution so that we might try to dissect it.

Comment: Another suggestion: what happens if you pick an ansatz that $X$ is equal to some minor modification of the solution to the equation with no stochastic term? The equation without the stochastic term is fairly straightforward to solve (implicitly at least) by elementary methods, so I would think that this would be illuminating.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Ian. Firstly, the solution is
\begin{align}
X_t = \frac{ (1+X_0) \exp(2bW_t) + X_0 - 1 }{(1+X_0)\exp(2bW_t)+1 - X_0}
\end{align}

Comment: When I apply Ito's formula to $h(t,W_t)$ (which I will write generically as $h(t,w)$), I get (writing $h$ for $h(t,W_t)$)

Comment: \begin{align}
\frac{ \partial h}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2} b^2 \frac{ \partial^2 h}{\partial w^2}(1-h^2) = -b^2 h(1-h)^2
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\frac{ \partial h}{\partial w} = b \sqrt{1 - h^2}
\end{align}

Solving the second one would give some $\sin$ and $\arcsin$. This is troubling because we shouldn't have that in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your system of PDEs in the term:
$ \frac{1}{2} b^{2} \frac{\partial^{2}h}{\partial w^{2}} (1-h^{2}) $

Don't you have an extra $b^{2}$ there?